# GWT - Upload and get files uploaded with FileUpload

Tags: file-upload, gwt

I'm using FileUpload class for uploading multiple files. Since **i do not have the choice to use a library** (like gwt-upload or others), I created the class **MultiFileUpload** :

```
public class MultiFileUpload extends FileUpload {
    public MultiFileUpload() {
        this.getElement().setAttribute("multiple", "multiple");
        this.setTitle("Select files");
    }
}
```

I added it to my pannel and can select multiple files successfuly :

```
private MultiFileUpload upload = new MultiFileUpload();
upload.getElement().setId("files");
grid.setWidget(2, 1, upload);
```

**My problem is:**
I cannot get the path of each file for sending it to another service (from another module created with Jave Entreprise Edition aka jee,  where I should use paths).

**What I tried**

- Getting files from FileUpload

```
upload.getElement.getgetChildCount(); ==> equal 0
upload.getFileName(); ==> null
```

- I tried using js:

```
private static native boolean validateFiles() /*-{
        var filesCount = $wnd.$('input:file')[0].files.length;
        for(i = 0; i<filesCount; i++){
        console.log($wnd.$('input:file')[0].files[i].path) //==> path is undefined
        }
}-*/;
```

- Using DOM:

```
Element e =  DOM.getElementById("files");
e.getgetChildCount(); ==> equal 0
```

*Any help is much appreciated.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I send files and all form data in a POST request to the servlet:

```
form.setAction(UPLOAD_ACTION_URL);
form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
```

Then in my servlet, i get files path from the request:

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

Iterator<FileItem> iter = items.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = iter.next();
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                File uploadedFile = new File(fileName);
                item.write(uploadedFile);
              }
}
```